# Why does my regular (XB360) joystick work but my virtual one won't?

Tags: unity, c#, android, input, joystick

I have my input manager setup properly before you ask. I am trying to get a virtual joystick working (notably [this](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/15233) one and I've tried Unity's included ones in the SA's too) but it simply won't work for some reason.

The thing of it is is that the 360 controller works but not the virtual joystick doesn't. Why not and how do I get it to work?

Code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour {

    public float moveSpeed;
    private Rigidbody myRigidbody;

    private Vector3 moveInput;
    private Vector3 moveVelocity;

    private Camera mainCamera;

    public GunController theGun;

    public bool useController;
    public bool useAndroidControls;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start ()
    {
        myRigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        mainCamera = FindObjectOfType<Camera>();    
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update ()
    {
        moveInput = new Vector3(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal"), 0f, Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical"));
        moveVelocity = moveInput * moveSpeed;

        //Rotate with mouse.
        if (!useController)
        {
            Ray cameraRay = mainCamera.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
            Plane groundPlane = new Plane(Vector3.up, Vector3.zero);
            float rayLength;

            if (groundPlane.Raycast(cameraRay, out rayLength))
            {
                Vector3 pointToLook = cameraRay.GetPoint(rayLength);
                Debug.DrawLine(cameraRay.origin, pointToLook, Color.blue);

                transform.LookAt(new Vector3(pointToLook.x, transform.position.y, pointToLook.z));
            }

            if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
            {
                theGun.isFiring = true;
            }
            if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
            {
                theGun.isFiring = false;
            }
        }
        if (useAndroidControls)
        {

        }

        //Rotae with controller

        if (useController)
        {
            Vector3 playerDirection = Vector3.right * Input.GetAxisRaw("RHorizontal") + Vector3.forward * -Input.GetAxisRaw("RVertical");
            if(playerDirection.sqrMagnitude > 0.0f)
            {
                transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(playerDirection, Vector3.up);
            }
            moveInput = new Vector3(Input.GetAxisRaw("LHorizontal"), 0f, Input.GetAxisRaw("LVertical"));
            moveVelocity = moveInput * moveSpeed;
        }
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        myRigidbody.velocity = moveVelocity;
    }
}
```

Input Manager Screenshot:

[image]

Also I'm aware of third-party extensions that can help but I'd rather do this for free and not resort to that.

Comment: As a general practice on this site (or when discussing dev issues wherever), we should always describe the *specific way in which* something "doesn't work," rather than just leaving it there. As we all know too well, there are about a million ways for things to go wrong in gamedev - from nothing happening at all to our game crashing and every form of absurd or chaotic behaviour in between - so clearly describing your symptoms is important to help track down issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the tutorial video says on their Unity page, you have to use the `CnInputManager` class in the `CnControls` namespace instead of the `Input` class:

```
CnInputManager.getAxis("yourAxis")
```